# Can't gain access to my database created though Visual Studio? 

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have created a database **emailDatabase**, its stored in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

In Visual Studio, I use the `Server Explorer`, click the add new connection button.

The add connection dialog box appears.

Under server name I use the dropdown box and select `DEV-5\SQLEXPRESS`. I use Windows authentication.

In the `Connect to` section at the bottom, the dropdown displays: `Master, Model, msdb` and `tempdb` and does not display my `emailDatabase`.

So I select `Attach Database File` and click browse and follow

```
local C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

and select my email database.

The following error occurs :

> emailDatabase
>   You don not have permission to open this file.
>   Contact file owner or an administrator to obtain permission.

I think my problem is i saved my database wrong, I need to make a back up or something like that. if that's the case please tel me how to make a backup and so on. I really need to move forward from this problem.

When I created my database I right-clicked on databases in SQL Server Management Studio and said new database, then I added columns with a query. then file save all.

How can I get a copy of my database file with all the permissions I need to use it in visual Studio??

Comment: Did you connect to `DEV-5\SQLEXPRESS` with your SQL Server Management Studio as well, when you created the database? Or is there a chance you might have created the database on a different **instance** (copy) of SQL Server?

Comment: I have not restarted my VS, i will try that now, um no i did not connect to DEV-5\SQLEXPRESS or at least i don't think so, i'm unsure what it is, it was just an Available option in the drop down box in VS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you create a database **on the server** (using SQL Server Management Studio), you don't have to (and should not!) fiddle around with the database file(s) anymore - let the server handle that for you.

Instead: do a **Add Connection** in Visual Studio and then specify the server instance (`DEV-5\SQLEXPRESS`) and the database name (`emailDatabase`) in your connection dialog.

With this, you're connecting and using a SQL Server database the way it's intended to be used - on the SQL Server instance itself. This is much easier, and much less hassle, than having to struggle with "free-floating" `.mdf` files and attaching them to your solutions and stuff like that....

[image]

So here - fill in `DEV-5\SQLEXPRESS` into your "Server name" dropdown, and then use the "Select or enter database name" option and enter your database name (or pick it from the dropdown) - it should be there!

**DO NOT** use the "Attach a database file" option - this is the free-floating `.mdf` "feature" which is rather clumsy and hard to use and error-prone - again: I recommend **not** using that...

Comment: I have not touched any of the files, i created my Database in MS SQL Server then clicked save all, and now i'm trying to locate it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes i get to that screen and have it like yours, but in the select or enter a database name, mine is not in the drop down? in my question i mention that only the master, Model, msdb and tempdb are there.

Comment: What can i do, or what didn't i do to get my database to be in that drop down box??

Comment: I have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 full version, when i start it the connect to server dialog box appears: Server type = Database engine, Server name = (local), Athentication = windows, then i click connect and i can view my databases. i have system databases with master, Model, msdb and tempdb.and then a folder after that that says email database. so its there

Comment: @Pomster: if you connect to `(local)`, then you create your database on the **default instance** on your machine. In that case, you need to also input `(local)` into the "Server name:" dropdown box in the Visual Studio dialog to connect to **that instance** where you created your database! You definitely have two instances - the default (`(local)`) and that Express (`DEV-5\SQLEXPRESS`) - this is like **two separate** SQL Servers alltogether - you need to be aware **where** you create your database - you cannot pick it from the other instance, obviously....

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much, at least i know where i went wrong, thank you, you have been a great help, so i should just put local into Visual studio and i should pick it up?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and I realised the problem was not in VS2010 but my SQLserver.
My instance name is **OMAFANO** ,and that's what my MSSQL connected to under Server Name. Now here's the catch,click on that and connect to **OMAFANO\SQLEXPRESS** and create all your databases and tables there if you want them to show up in VS2010 the way u stated up there. So under server name in VS2010 also write **INSTANCENAME\SQLEXPRESS** if you want to see your newly created databases etc. Take a look at the picture:
[image]

Comment: Thank you this was my exact problem! I suggest adding an edit to your post that if you already have SQL Server open and you're connected, you can also see this connection string at the top of the object explorer, that was how I found it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had it figured out but problems continue to pop up. So ...

IGNORE EVERYTHING BELOW THIS LINE.

After hours of tinkering I finally figured out how to use SSMS to connect to a SQLServer 2008 database that was created in VS2010, and it is relatively simple. But from the number of unanswered questions all over the place not well documented. Here's how to do it:

1. In VS right click the project in SolutionExplorer and select Add new item then select Data then SQLServer database. It will prompt you to save it in the app_data folder and create the folder for you if it doesn't exist.
2. Find the Ssms.exe file (on my system it's in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE
3. Right click Ssms.exe and select Run as administrator.
4. After SSMS opens you can attach the project MDF. It will now be on your list of databases. The database name is a GUID.
5. You can even run aspnet_regsql against the database to add the Membership tables and sprocs.

IMPORTANT! You can manage this database with **EITHER** SMSS **OR** VS but not both at the same time. If you mess with the database from within VS using ServerExplorer you will break the SSMS connection. To fix that you will need to detach and reattach the database.

Answer (score 0):

Run Your Visual studio As Administrator
Go to Visual Studio instance i.e C#,C++ etc
Right click > Run as Administrator

Then now It may work

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a ssms2014 database from visual studio 2013, in the new connection wizard I had to change 'data source' from 'ms sql server database file' to '.net framework data provider for sql server..'. Then I was able to enter [computer name][username] for windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you just type your local server name "**sara-PC**" instead of 
"**sara-PC\SQLEXPRESS**"

Now you can access your database easily, you can see it in your dropdownlist.
And also please dont use file access method to attatch database, thats not good way.
Also you  can put ~....\Data and ~...\log file wherever you want by setting default location using server->rightclick->properties->Database settings.

Definitely this solves your issue.