# SQL server not showing up on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I have configured my SQL Server and it used to show the name of my computer when I was trying to make a connection to a table in the SQL server management center but now it doesn't show up. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here's an image to help:

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: Did you refresh it? `-_-` Or did you tried writing the same with your sql server management studio?

Comment: tried both doesn't seem to be showing up :/ i even restarted the server agent and the sql server integration services still nothing :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use your localhost name to connect to SQL server,

`localhost\(instance name)` or `.\(instance name)`

for example in my case I usually put in `localhost\sqlexpress`

or just `localhost`  or `127.0.0.1` or your network ip

and then you will be able to see your databases.

Another post with similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482113/cant-gain-access-to-my-database-created-though-visual-studio).
Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks it worked, although I'm still wondering why it doesn't show up though

Comment: @Suits999 the SQL Server Browser service is what provides that functionality. You should check that the service is running and that your firewall isn't blocking UDP port 1434

Answer (score 1):

You have to type it in I think e.g. like above but a quick guide (take less than 15 min to get the basics you are looking for) I suggest to take a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb466226.aspx?wt.slv=topsectionsee#formsoverdata

Enjoy

Kurt F.

Answer (score 1):

check that your SQL Server Browser service is running - that's what provides that list of servers. There's more information about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165724%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

It requires UDP port 1434 which may be blocked by your firewall